# Read XML from the internet addrrss

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

Can anyone explain me if it is possible to read an xml page from the internet and pursed it into the multiple raw database table from mssql?

im having a page called:

```
https://mywebsite.com/api/?u=xxxxxxx&p=yyyyyy&fields=CallerID&format=xml
```

This will give me below information:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below
<records>
<call>
<callingnumber>357994</callingnumber>
</call>
<call>
<callingnumber>357996</callingnumber>
</call>
<call>
<callingnumber>357995</callingnumber>
</call>
</records>
```

The thing is this content can not be download as xml inside the server. So mssql has to read the file online.

i tried to use the below code but it comes with error:

```
DECLARE @x XML
SELECT @x = cast(x.bulkColumn as XML) 
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'https://mywebsite.com/api/?u=xxxxxxx&p=yyyyyy&fields=CallerID&format=xml', SINGLE_CLOB) AS x

select @x;
```

Error was:

```
Cannot bulk load because the file "https://mywebsite.com/api/?u=xxxxxxx&p=yyyyyy&fields=CallerID&format=xml" could not be opened. Operating system error code 123(The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.).
```

Can anyone help me solve this problem.

Regards

Comment: it is never a good idea to directly load a file without some kind of parsing and error checking.  Imagine what kind of bad data could get into your system, or, if things are really messed up, you could have a Little Bobby Tables situation.

Comment: @MarshallTigerus Thanks for the info, but these data are in xml has been checked before add to that server. Its some sort of Caller id information. and of course every 2 day we check these data in case of any problem. could you please guide me how to read them?

Comment: You are treating a URL as a file, which does not work...you need to make a web request. Doing this in SQL is a bit complicated. Check this example: http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=111356

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer how to do this in a simple way.
You can create a powershell script and call it ex. script.ps1

```
[xml]$x = (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString("https://yourwebsite.com/api/?u=xxxxxx&p=xxxxxx&format=xml")
$x.Save(‘C:\folder\name.xml’);
```

Run the script from Stored procedure :

```
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File c:\script.ps1'
```